# How do I create a High-Order React Component connected to Redux using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-router

I need to create a React High-Order component to protect routes in my app against users that don't have an access token. Then using that HOC wrap a Component like this on parent component:

```
<Route
    exact
    path={INDEX_URL}
    render={isAuthenticated((props: any) => (<LandingPage {...props} />))}
/>
```

I'm using Typescript and I'm having some issues with the connect function and withRouter from react-router-dom.

Can someone help me, please?
Thank you and have a great weekend!

I've already tried to extend my interface with RouterProps and/or withRouter but none worked. It seems that is some typing related issue, but I can't figure out exactly what it is.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as H from 'history';

// Constants
import { LOGIN_URL } from '../../../data/constants/index.constants';

interface IAuthenticatedProps {
    accessToken: string | null;
    location: H.Location;
}

interface IAuthenticatedState {
    isAuthenticated: boolean | undefined;
}

/**
 * @description Higher-order component (HOC) to wrap Authenticated pages
 * @date 2019-01-18
 * @class Authenticated
 * @extends {React.Component<IAuthenticatedProps, any>}
 */
const isAuthenticated = (ComposedComponent: any) => {
    class Authenticated extends React.Component<
        IAuthenticatedProps,
        IAuthenticatedState
    > {
(...)
    function mapStateToProps(state: any) {
        return {
            accessToken: state.authentication.accessToken,
        };
    }

    return withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticated));
};

export default isAuthenticated;
```

I expected no issues, but Typescript is giving me this:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'ConnectedComponentClass<typeof Authenticated, Pick<IAuthenticatedProps, "location">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>>'.
  Type 'ConnectedComponentClass<typeof Authenticated, Pick<IAuthenticatedProps, "location">>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, any>'.
    Type 'Component<Pick<IAuthenticatedProps, "location">, any, any>' is not assignable to type 'Component<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, any, any>'.
      Types of property 'props' are incompatible.
        Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<Pick<IAuthenticatedProps, "location">>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>>'.
          Type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<Pick<IAuthenticatedProps, "location">>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>>': history, match [2345]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withRouter()` has the effect of providing props to the component that it wraps. Therefore, in order to use it, the component you want to wrap has to *expect* those props. In this case, `Authenticated` is only expecting `IAuthenticatedProps`, but `withRouter()` provides many more. So TypeScript is complaining because `withRouter()` is trying to provide props to `Authenticated` that `Authenticated` doesn't say it expects.

The props that `withRouter()` provides are defined in the interface `RouteComponentProps`. Try adding that to your prop type for `Authenticated`:

```
  class Authenticated extends React.Component<
    IAuthenticatedProps & RouteComponentProps<{}>,
    IAuthenticatedState
  > {
    // ...
  }
```

You can also remove `location` from your `IAuthenticatedProps` interface as that is also included in the `RouteComponentProps` interface.

One more problem is that the `render` prop in `Route` expects a function, not any old React component type. Since `isAuthenticated()` returns a `React.ComponentClass`, you'll need to do something like the following:

```
const Authenticated = isAuthenticated(LandingPage);
// ...
<Route
  exact
  path={INDEX_URL}
  render={(props: any) => <Authenticated {...props} />}
/>
```

Comment: Great, that helped on the HOC component side, thanks! 

However, on the parent component Typescript now throws me another error:
(Gee, I'm sorry I'm a n00b at commenting )

Comment: [ts]Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<Pick<IAuthenticatedProps & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>, "location" | "history" | "match" | "staticContext">, never>, any>' is not assignable to type '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>) => ReactNode'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<Pick<Pick<IAuthenticatedProps & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>, "location" | "history" | "match" | "staticContext">, never>, any>' provides no match for the signature '(props: RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>): ReactNode'

Comment: Can you give an example of how you're calling from the parent component?

Comment: Ah never mind I see your issue. I will update my answer.

Comment: Of course, here it goes:
https://gist.github.com/JoaoTMDias/d11d44f220bd4c9515c8d53b84227b11

Comment: Man, that's awesome @err1100!. Thank you so much, and thank you for the explanation. Is there any way I can buy you a beer or something?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, React is throwing me in the browser console another error: "Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it." 

Comment: Whoops, that's my bad. `isAuthenticated(LandingPage)` is itself a component class, not a rendered component. I was not actually creating the component itself. Fixed the answer.